# How do I rank up a class?

Tags: mass-effect-andromeda

Apparently ranking up a class [gives more than just cosmetic bonuses](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/304538/what-does-ranking-up-do) (namely, skill points).  Other than pulling the same card again from supply packs, are there any other ways to rank up a class?

Comment: AFAIK packs are the only way to level up a multiplayer class. Kind of a  frustrating ceiling to hit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

You can level the class by getting experience in matches, but ranking it up is done exclusively by getting cards in packs.

Comment: damn, that's annoying